# video steaming using django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

RestAPI Streem Video How i can do for this

based requeste input:Video,Timesteemp,
output: Return Based on Timeframe or base64 data Next Video Chunks send back